# Помогите, пожалуйста)

Tags: словообразование

Укажите номера словообразовательных цепочек, в которых нарушена последовательность образования слов. Исправьте ошибки.

1. красить-перекрашивать-перекрашиваться
2. сказать-предсказать-предсказатель-предсказательница
3. учить-учитель-учительство-учительствовать
4. валить-переваливать-вперевалку
5. варить-сварить-сварка-газосварочный
6. пар-парить-испарить-испарение
7. катить-раскатить-раскат-раскатисто

Comment: Есть собственные соображения?

Comment: Ну я так думаю,что ошибки в 4 и 7,но не уверена,да и исправить не знаю как)

Answer (score 2):

1. красить-**перекрасить** - перекрашивать-перекрашиваться
2. валить-**перевалить** - **перевалка** - вперевалку
3. катить-раскатить-раскат- **раскатистый** - раскатисто